# Excel Spreadsheet - One to Many matching excercise

Tags: excel

Basically from the picture linked here, what I'm trying to do is to look for a formula that can compare the value of the second row, with the values of the first column. If it finds that, for example, the first cell has the letter "A" in it then that row cell for A would get a yes, otherwise it would remain blank

Is this possible in excel?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `ISNUMBER()` & `SEARCH()` within an `IF()`

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$2,$A3)),"Yes","")
```

Fill Down & Fill Right!!!

---

You can also use the formula as shown below, and showing the cells as `Yes` using a custom formatting though it will be a *façade*, still.

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$2,$A3))
```

And Fill down & fill right, next select all the cells, where you applied the formula, Press `CTRL + 1` to open **Format Cells Dialogue**, **Number Tab**, **Category** will be **Custom** and type by removing the *General*,

```
[=1]"Yes";;
```

So the above `Custom Formatting` turns the cells which returns `1` to `Yes` while the `0's` as `blank`.

Comment: Nice solution. We can also consider `XMATCH()`.

Comment: Nice one, it's gotten a bit more complex now so I'll see how this one goes. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Harun24hr Sir, yes we can consider but we have to wrap it under another `IF()` or use custom formatting for the same.

Comment: @MasatoIndou if this seems complex to you, then I do not know what is easier. Because the formula shown above uses to primary functions, to get the output. So basically `SEARCH()` finds the position of the character and when found we are wrapping it within a `ISNUMBER()` to return as `TRUE` last we are wrapping the whole within an `IF()` to display `Yes` and `blank`.

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya: Not what I meant :) The formula is pretty simple to use and understand, it's the conditions of my comparisons that turned a bit more complex is all. I've basically got a column of 'Translation' text which I'm using on another column using Free Text to say basically the same thing I've put in the 'Translation' column (its a term standardization exercise)

Answer (score 1):

`XMATCH()` also can be considered with wild card character matching mode..

```
=IFNA(XMATCH("*"&B$2&"*",$A3,2),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a shot too. Because I'm dealing with a lot of free text and trying to get some kind of standardization going, it is getting a bit tricky getting this matching thing going.